# using react-native expo how would grab vaiue of a key

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I am using react naitve expo with firebase realtime database I have just a simple list of name, email address and score in my database  I want to be able to pull the high score our so I do an order by child and I choose scores as the child and limit to first my snap shot brings back the correct entry but when I do a snapshot.key I get the child score but not the value which I want to take and add to state.

I gave tried `snapshot.key.val()` but that gives me null,
as does `snapshot.child.val()`.

my databases

```
memory-game
 {
```

"users" : {
    "TtDcqyNkhXSUCpzHeI9jELo7DCl1" : {
      "Score" : 51,
      "first_name" : "Joe",
      "gmail" : "watsonr@gmail.com",
      "last_name" : "watson",
      "locale" : "en",
      "profile_picture":"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-616Zg1h61BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/
    },
    "dxuCP7if4hWFoP8iO69ndD7gOVq1" : {
      "Score" : 25,
      "first_name" : "jay",
      "gmail" : "jayd@cmail.com",
      "last_name" : "watson",
      "locale" : "en",
      "profile_picture" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-bzA9FCFRNqc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3re5n7l6GrqFFQK8PnySQ3cPY6T9ug/s96-c/photo.jpg"
    }
  }
}

```
firebase.database().ref("users/score").orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(1)
        .once("value",snapshot =>{
            const data = snapshot.key.val("score")
            console.log (data)
             console.log("testing")

        })
```

Comment: Please replace the schematic depiction of your database structure with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).